# Filter a dataframe based on values matching/containing in particular column in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

I have a df1 which contains a column named Id while there is another df2 with a column named Test_Ids_flow which contains a number of Id's (some included from df1, some not). I need to filter out only those rows in df2 which contain the Id in df1.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Id':["42","75","36","12"],
                    'Name':['Apple','Strawberry','Banana','Pear']})


df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Test_Ids_Flow':["42,4,6,10","4,8,3,9","4,8,5,75","1,6,12,90","5,36,10,94","6,4,3,60","18,25,65,72"]})
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try with `pd.DataFrame.str.split(',')` to get the list of ids, and then check with `pd.Series.isin` and `pd.Series.any()` to check if the list contains at least one element of `df.Id`:

```
mask=df2['Test_Ids_Flow'].str.split(',').apply(lambda x: df.Id.isin(x).any())
#Same as:   mask=[df.Id.isin(l).any()  for l in df2['Test_Ids_Flow'].str.split(',')]
  
df2[mask]
```

Same as:

```
df2[df2.Test_Ids_Flow.str.split(',', expand=True).isin(df.Id.tolist()).any(1)]
```

Output:

```
 Test_Ids_Flow
0     42,4,6,10
2      4,8,5,75
3     1,6,12,90
4    5,36,10,94
```